# need to customize id

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have id automatically generated like

```
service_type  service_id
hair          1
skin          2
```

i have a select box like

```
<label class="label-style">Service Type:</label>
                                <span><select id="service_type" name="service_type"  class="form-control" required >
                                  <option></option>
                                  <option type="brillare">Brillare</option>
                                  <option type="hair">Hair</option>
                                </select></span>
```

According to select of service type need to change service_id like

I need to do it in laravel

```
service_type  service_id
hair          hr_1
skin           sk_1
hair          hr_2
skin           sk_2
```

Comment: I assume you want/need `SELECT ... , CASE WHEN service_type = 'hair' THEN CONCAT('hr_', service_id)  WHEN service_type = 'skin' THEN CONCAT('sk_', service_id) END  AS service_id ....`  ?  Otherwise see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "need to change service_id" - I don't see any reason for that in your question. You are probably looking at the problem from the wrong perspective.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax method:
if you have another input with the id of service_id, then the id of service type will be showen in service_id input.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).on('change','#service_type',function(){

            var service_id =$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:'{!!URL::to('getserviceid')!!}',
                data:{'type':service_id },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#service_id').val(data);
                },
                error:function(){

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

my web.php:

```
Route::get('getserviceid','PageController@getserviceid');
```

PageController:

```
 public function getserviceid(Request $request)
    {
        $id = DB::table('services')->where('type', $request->type)->value('id');
        return response()->json($id);
    }
```